What is the translation of "nosebleed section" in French?
From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosebleed_section:

In the United States, Canada and Australia, the nosebleed section are the seats of a public area, usually an athletic stadium or gymnasium, that are highest and, usually, farthest from the desired activity.

What is the translation of "nosebleed section" in French?
Google Translate returns "section de saignement de nez", which I believe is incorrect. Linguee returns  similar translations.

The closest would be the poulailler (chicken coop) but as far as I know, it is only used with theaters.
TLFi

B.− THÉÂTRE, familier Galerie supérieure, très éloignée de la scène, où les places sont les moins chères.

Edit: Here is poulailler used in a stadium context: La victoire de la France vue du poulailler, Le Parisien, 1998.

Thx! Why would poulailler refer to galerie supérieure?. Btw TLFi also mentions "paradis".

@FranckDernoncourt This meaning of paradis is long forgotten although It somewhat survives in Les enfants du paradis.
